# What setting controls the background color on highlighted list items in the Variables view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I like to use a dark theme. When I do, the Variables view sometimes highlights items using an extremely bright yellow color, with light gray text, meaning the text is impossible to read.

What setting controls that yellow color?

I would love to post a picture but I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: Add the link to the picture even if you can't embed it. It will still help and we can edit it in for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you are talking about. Is it like this?

[image: Example]

The settings are in Window → Preferences → General → Editors → Text Editors → Annotations. The ones you want are probably **Occurrences** and **Write Occurrences**. You can change the **Highlighted** to something else, such as **Underlined** or **Squiggly Line**. You can also change the highlight **Color**.

[image: Annotations]